# C programming: How to use gdb with Makefile and command line arguments?

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, command-line-arguments

To create the .out executable, I have to enter:

```
$: make
$: myprogram.out name.ged
```

My program incorporates a command line argument, thus the "name.ged".

Whenever I run gdb after getting a segmentation fault (core dumped), I enter:

```
$: gdb a.out core
(gdb): bt
```

I then use the back trace command, and gdb returns:

```
#0 0x4a145155 in ?? ()
#1 0x08a16ce0 in ?? ()
```

I even tried using the up command t move up the stack, but still no luck. I can't tell which line in my program is giving me the seg fault. gdb works with my other programs that do not involve a Makefile and command arguments, so I'm wondering if my commands are incorrect.

Comment: You need to compile with the `-g` flag. As you have not posted the Makefile I cannot give you any further help.

Comment: So would the command be gcc -g myprogram.out name.ged?

Comment: In the make file there is a command to compile the code (gcc ...) That command needs the -g flag to add additional information for gdb to work effectively.

Comment: Also, if the program is `myprogram.out`, it should be `gdb myprogram.out core` not `gdb a.out core`. It could be any old `a.out` sitting there.

Answer (score 11):

*Summarizing the comments (before anyone else does :).*

Your executable file is missing the symbolic information that gdb needs to display the relevant source code. You need to add the `-g` option to the compile command and produce a new executable. Then re-run your failing test to produce a new core file. **gdb** with this executable and core will be able to show you the stack of function calls using `backtrace`.

In a makefile, the easiest way to do this is to add (to) the `CFLAGS` variable which is used with the implicit .o.c rule.

```
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -Wextra
```

You can also add this directly to the command-line (assuming a decent shell :). This sets the value as an environment variable during the execution of the `make` command (and sub-commands).

```
$ CFLAGS='-g -Wall -Wextra' make
```

I'd actually recommend you add this to your bash .profile, so you always get the most information from the compiler.

```
CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra'
```

Then, when you need it, put this in the makefile to make a debuggable executable:

```
CFLAGS+= -g
```